# Ruby: what is an easy way to check of all values in a 2D array are the same in a particular column or row?

Tags: ruby

```
[[0, 1, 2],
 [2, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 2]]
```

What is an easy way to check of this matrix has all values down a column the same?

```
[[0, 1, 0],
 [2, 2, 2],
 [0, 1, 2]]
```

And then horizontally?

Comment: Just curious, are you writing a sudoku solver?

Comment: no, lol, Tic Tac toe. Trying to do it with variable width.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.

```
a.map{|row|row[x]}.uniq.size == 1
```

or

```
a.transpose[x].uniq.size == 1
```

2.

```
a[x].uniq.size == 1
```

Comment: in the second one, what is x?

Comment: @DerNalia, row number. P.S.: use `@` and nick, if you want that man to see notification about your comment.

Answer (score 1):

To check whether there's a row in which all items are the same, you can do:

```
array.any? do |row|
  row.all? {|item| row[0] == item }
end
```

To check whether there's a column, you can first transpose the array and then do the same.